# AS3 SQLite DELETE statement don't give result

Tags: database, sqlite, actionscript-3, events

When I delete row from DB, it deletes row, but I don't get event, that it deleted row (I need to refresh list after user delete something). Here are methods for handle results from DB:

```
    private final function onReady(e:EventWithMessage):void
    {
        switch (action)
        {
            case "get files":
                dispatchEvent(new EventWithMessage(EventWithMessage.FILES, {files: null}));
                break;
            case "save note":
                dispatchEvent(new EventWithMessage(EventWithMessage.SAVED, { ID:e.message.ID } ));
                break;
            case "delete note":
                // Saving and getting files above work! And this is not working
                dispatchEvent(new EventWithMessage(EventWithMessage.DELETED, { } ));
                break;
        }
        action = null;
    }

    private final function onData(e:EventWithMessage):void
    {
        DATA = e.message.data;
        switch (action)
        {
            case "get files": 
                // some code was here
                dispatchEvent(new EventWithMessage(EventWithMessage.FILES, {files: fileArray}));
                break;
            case "load note":
                dispatchEvent(new EventWithMessage(EventWithMessage.FILE, { text:DATA[0].text } ));
                break;
            case "delete note":
                // And even here it isn't working
                dispatchEvent(new EventWithMessage(EventWithMessage.DELETED, { } ));
                break;
        }
        action = null;
    }
```

Method for DELETE:

```
    public final function deleteNote(ID:int):void
    {
        SQLiteManager.SQLM.Operations(String("DELETE FROM Notes WHERE id = " + ID));
        action = "delete note";
    }
```

And methods in SQLiteManager (my class):

```
    public final function Operations(command:String, parameters:Array = null)
    {
        statement = new SQLStatement ();
        statement.sqlConnection = connection;
        statement.text = command;
        if (parameters && parameters.length > 0)
        {
            for (i = 0; i < parameters.length; i++)
            {
                statement.parameters[i] = parameters[i];
            }
        }
        statement.execute (-1,responder);
    }
```

Responder has two methods :

```
    private final function handleSuccess (result:SQLResult):void
    {
        if (result.data)
        {
            dispatchEvent(new EventWithMessage(EventWithMessage.SQLDATA, { data:result.data} ));
        } 
        else 
        {
            dispatchEvent(new EventWithMessage(EventWithMessage.READY, { ID:result.lastInsertRowID } ));
        }
    }

    private final function handleError (e:SQLError):void
    {
        dispatchEvent (new EventWithMessage(EventWithMessage.ERROR,{error:e.message}));
    }
```

Is there any mistake or it just don't give any result after DELETE? Help please.

**EDIT:** While I wait for answer - I use timer (1 second after DELETE it refresh file list). Maybe it's an good alternative to event?

**EDIT 2** action variable is null, when it comes to dispatch event O_o Why it is null? Oh my god.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED!!! There was an event, I made some "trace" and found out that problem was in action variable, it was null, when event had been dispatched. I deleted lines **action = null;** and now everything works well. Hooray :)